# How do I reuse a class in a different form when a class method is run in a BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I had this function in Form1 which worked well. The idea was to retrieve some text from a big xml file. So in the Form1 construction I did:

```
r = new StreamReader(@"D:\Deponia_Work\Deponia Extracted Files\000004aa.xml");
f = r.ReadToEnd();
r.Close();
```

The variable f is string.

Now I had in Form1 this function I called test() which was doing the retrieving/extract of the text from the big 000004aa.xml file.

```
private void test()
        {
            int countFiles = 0;
            byte[] a;
            string startTag = "T256=\"";
            string endTag = "\"";
            int index = 0;
            int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
            int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
            int fileLength = f.Length;
            w = new StreamWriter(@"d:\testingdeponias.txt");
            while (true)
            {
                if (index > f.LastIndexOf(startTag))
                {
                    break;
                }
                int startTagIndex = f.IndexOf(startTag, index);
                int stringIndex = startTagIndex + startTagWidth;
                index = stringIndex;

                int endTagIndex = f.IndexOf(endTag, index);
                int stringLength = endTagIndex - stringIndex;
                if (stringLength == 0)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    string test = f.Substring(stringIndex, stringLength);
                    if (test.Contains("&lt;pa&gt;"))
                    {
                        string t = "&lt;pa&gt;";
                        int y = t.Length;
                        string test1 = test.Substring(0, stringLength - y);
                        listBox1.Items.Add(test1);
                        w.WriteLine(test1);
                    }
                    //else
                    // {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(test);
                    w.WriteLine(test);
                    // }
                }
            }
            w.Close();
        }
```

Then I added to Form1 a new backgroudnworker2 events:

This is the DoWork event:

```
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker2 = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            lists1.extractTextDeponia(worker2, backgroundWorker2, listBox1, textBox1,f, w, e);
        }
```

And this is the button click event where I start the backgroundworker:

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

In the new class I created a new function public function that get some variables from Form1.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace List_Words
{
    class Lists
    {
        
        public void List_Words()
        {
           
        }

        public void extractTextDeponia(BackgroundWorker worker, BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker2, ListBox lbox , TextBox tbox , StreamWriter streamW , string read, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
```

My problem is how to change and to convert the test() function from Form1 to the new class into the new function so it will also work and use with the backgroundworker2?

I tried to use/add FileStream there and added while loop which will read line by line but it didn't work good.

** This is the new class with the function there which doesn't act as it was test() in Form1**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace List_Words
{
    class Lists
    {
        
        public void List_Words()
        {
           
        }

        public void extractTextDeponia(BackgroundWorker worker, BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker2, ListBox lbox , TextBox tbox , StreamWriter streamW , string read, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string startTag = "T256=\"";
            string endTag = "\"";
            int index = 0;
            int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
            int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
            int fileLength = read.Length;
            using (var fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Deponia_Work\Deponia Extracted Files\000004aa.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {

                using (var h = new StreamReader(fs))
                {
                    string line;
                    line = h.ReadLine();
                    while ((line = h.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                        {
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            int percent = (int)(fs.Position * 100 / fs.Length);
                            backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(percent);
                            if (index > read.LastIndexOf(startTag))
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            int startTagIndex = read.IndexOf(startTag, index);
                            int stringIndex = startTagIndex + startTagWidth;
                            index = stringIndex;

                            int endTagIndex = read.IndexOf(endTag, index);
                            int stringLength = endTagIndex - stringIndex;
                            if (stringLength == 0)
                            {
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                line = read.Substring(stringIndex, stringLength);
                                if (line.Contains("&lt;pa&gt;"))
                                {
                                    string t = "&lt;pa&gt;";
                                    int y = t.Length;
                                    string test1 = line.Substring(0, stringLength - y);
                                    if (lbox.InvokeRequired)
                                    {
                                        lbox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { lbox.Items.Add(test1); }));
                                    }
                                    //w.WriteLine(test1);
                                    line = h.ReadLine();
                                    if (tbox.InvokeRequired)
                                    {
                                        tbox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { tbox.Text = test1; }));
                                    }
                                }
                                //else
                                // {
                                if (lbox.InvokeRequired)
                                {
                                    lbox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { lbox.Items.Add(line); }));
                                }
                                //w.WriteLine(line);
                                if (tbox.InvokeRequired)
                                {
                                    tbox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { tbox.Text = line; }));
                                }
                                // }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            streamW = new StreamWriter(@"d:\testingdeponias.txt");
            streamW.AutoFlush = true;
            streamW.Write(read);
            streamW.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

And in form1 I'm calling it as:

```
BackgroundWorker worker2 = sender as BackgroundWorker;
lists1.extractTextDeponia(worker2, backgroundWorker2, listBox1, textBox1,w, f, e);
```

w is stream writer f is string and e is the backgroundowrker2 DoWork e variable
As I showed above I'm using f in Form1 constructor to read the big xml file but I also do it in the new class and function with FileStream what a mess. **

Comment: All of these things can be as uncoupled as you want.  The background worker is a class instance, you can define it anywhere.  The Filestream object is the same.  It makes no difference where you call them, as long as they can see each other from within the application (public).  So when your saying  "it didnt work good", what exactly was the problem?

Comment: When i said "it didnt work good" i mean that when it was only in Form1 without using the backgroundworker2 it was working as i wanted it to work. But as soon as i moved to it to the new class it extracted moew strings i didnt want it to. I mean it extracted more tags and not only text from the xml. And in the new class in the function im using a variable string read wich is string f in Form1 and in Form1 string f is reading to the end the big xml file but in the new class and function im also using FileStream wich is also reading this big xml file. Then i mixed the variables in the new class.

Comment: I will add to my post the function and the code as it is now in the new class. Its not giving me errors but it dosent work as i need.

Comment: Ok, well you need to give specifics about what your problems are when you post a question (especially error codes if there are any). That will keep people like me from spending time trying to figure out what you want and coding solutions that you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may help is to change your programming mindset a bit.  Instead of thinking of Forms and Events, think of Data Entities and Actions on those data entities, then you can use a Service type pattern.

So what you would do is create a Service Class, that does whatever is you want to happen.  Since you are using the background worker, I would create it as an instance class instead of static.

```
public class FileWorkerService
{
   private BackgroundWorker _worker;

   public FileWorkerService()
    {
       _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    }

   public void ReadFileAndProcessIt()
    {
      if (!_worker.IsBusy)
        {
          _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    } 
 }
```

Now, just wire up the _worker the same way you did before with your events and your service class is ready to do work.

In order to get it to do something, you simply create an instance of it and call the function that starts the worker.

So on your form button click you would have...

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var newService = new FileWorkerService();
            newService.ReadFileAndProcessIt();
        }
```

> > > =================  EDIT ==================================
> > >       -- Added how to update progress of background worker from within service.
> > >       <<< ==========================================================

Inside your FileWorkerService class

```
public void SetWorkerProgress(int currentValue)
{
   _worker.ReportProgress(currentValue);
}
```

To call outside the class, from your main form, you would do...

```
newService.SetWorkerProgress(whatever);
```

Comment: David                                                                                                                                       And how do i change/use the test() function to work with the backgroundworker ? Lets say i dont change anything in the test() function as it was in Form1 but i need somehow to pass from variables to the backgroundworker for example the  backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(percent); i used it with FileStream before but lets say i dont want to change anything in the test() function how can i report to the backgroundworker ?

Comment: Because the background worker belongs to the service class you created, your service class becomes the conduit.  You could either create an accessor so you can directly touch the background worker to your service class, or you can create a method that does what you want to the background worker.  I can't really format content here so I will edit the primary post

Comment: Are you having trouble getting the service worker to do what you want it to do, or are you having trouble getting the service worker to report its value back to the form and to display it before the entire job is processed (often an issue when dealing with long running processes and winforms)

Comment: David I mean in the test() function how do i calculate the percentages to report back ? I used FileStream before and did  int percent = (int)(fs.Position * 100 / fs.Length);
                            backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(percent); but if im not using FileStream just as the test() function it is as above how can i calculate the progress so i can make ReportProgress to the backgroundworker. My problem now is the calculation to report to the backgorundworker.